# Removing element using imacro

Tags: javascript, imacros

First of all I am new to imacros,I am trying to remove an element from a page using imacro in a random site, for which i have tried to use the javascript which throws me an error of `.remove() is not a function`. Following is the piece of code which i have been trying:

```
var macro = "";
macro +="SET !DATASOURCE mobidomains2.csv";
macro +="SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1";
macro ="SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE={{!COL1}}";
window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("results-explained").remove();
var ret="";
ret=iimPlay(macro);
```

I have also tried it with using `.removechild()`, so is there any way that I can delete a specific div using imacro with javascript? Thanking  you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You should iterate through the set and then call the `remove` method on each element. Also note [`ChildNode.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method is not widely-supported.

```
var collection = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("results-explained");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(collection, function(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

Comment: [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) is not supported by IE tho.

Comment: @A1rPun Yes, that's true.